# AS3 - Is it a good idea to make new .AS classes for ever object in a game?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to make new .AS files for each and every object in my game for the sake of versatility, dynamism, and organization. I mean, in the case of a shooter game, I want to make a new class file for every type of bullet with all of their unique properties all spelled out in their respective classes. I want to do the same thing for every type of enemy in the game.

This is all assuming there may be 10+ different types of enemies/bullets.

Some people have been pushing me to keep the values of each type of, for example, bullet in one class and then just change the variables depending on the type of bullet being fired. That doesn't sound too fun to me and I would rather just create a bunch of different class files and just push all of the bullets into a common array(which works so far), but I would really like to know if I have the right, or even good, idea by doing so.

Comment: Read a book on game design for AS3.0 is recommended to: 
this book is What kind of games you need to configure each Class are detailed about whether and to manage.

this is Amazon link:

[Foundation Game Design 1st](http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Game-Design-Flash-Foundations/dp/1430218215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344324950&sr=8-1&keywords=foundation+game+design)

[Foundation Game Design 2nd](http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Game-Design-ActionScript-3-0/dp/143023993X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1344324950&sr=8-2&keywords=foundation+game+design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, since bullets (or enemies, for that matter) represent the same family objects, it would make sense to have a common interface, or an abstract class, which is implemented, or extended by each concrete class. Is this a good idea? Let's think about it this way:

When you are creating the classes that will be used throughout your application, you essentially building an API. Good practice suggests that you should always program to an interface rather than an implementation. What this means is that your top-level classes, should not depend on low-level ones, but rather they should use abstractions. That way, the different-level components are loosely coupled and the overall code is more flexible. This principle is known as [Dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), and is one of the five principles of the [SOLID design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

The links provided should give some additional information on how to structure your code.

Have a great day!

Comment: I agree with @RomiHalasz. If you are writing a game to have fun, do what you feel most comfortable with, in my opinion. If you are writing this game to better your skills and want to continue to make bigger better games, it behooves you to make your classes more versatile and reusable than a specific Grunt.as. Future Joseph Wagner will thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it still be reusable and versatile if I made a separate .as file? Reusable in the way I could just copy the file and plug it into another game and versatile in the way that I could just alter variables of that single file depending on what I want it to do.

Comment: You definitely want to go this route for any serious project.

Comment: Joseph, if you do it that way, you might end up with a lot a files that that share attributes, and that's duplicating code. If you wanted to say, change one attribute type, or name, you have to repeat that operation for every class that has that certain property. Just like @LondonDrugs_MediaServices pointed out, inheritance will solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use inheritance to make it cleaner and more flexible with changes. Then even on multiple projects you can just extend the same generic base class.

Start with a base class (or interface) - Bullet.as for example - and put all the functionality and properties that are common to ALL bullets in that class. Anytime you have groups of bullets that share the same properties, keep making sub-classes.  So if you had multiple kinds of bullets that all explode on contact, you could have the following kind of setup:

```
public class Bullet {
    public function fire():void {};

    public property size:int;
    public property strength:Number;
    public property label:String;
    public property maxDistance:Number;
} 

public class ExplodingBullet extends Bullet {
    public property blastRadius:Number;

    public function explode():void {
        trace("Kaboom");
    }
}

public class BazookaBullet extends ExplodingBullet {
    public function BazookaBullet():void {
        blastRadius = 10;
        label = "Bazooka";
        size = 5;
        maxDistance = 120;
    }
}
```

This would give your bazooka bullets all the functionality of the class it extends.  There are a great many benefits to doing it this way as opposed to recreating all the same properties and methods in all your bullet classes.

Comment: Sweet. This is the direction I want to go. Thank you for the advice! :)

Comment: You should mark an answer as correct then,  and be sure to upvote RomiHalasz answer as it's the same kinda thing, I just tried to make it a bit easier to understand (and had already started typing it up when his answer came in).